# Нажатие клавиши как Event, а не в Update

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всегда смущала проверка нажатия клавиши ,например для движения, в `Update`. В событиях есть событие клика и прочее, но не самих клавиш. Существует ли интерфейс для этих дел или может кто-то знает как реализовать такой интерфейс на практике, чтобы считывалось нажатие по нажатию, а не `if'ы` в `Update`. Буду благодарен.

Comment: То что существует я уверен. Вопрос на самом деле интересный, попробую найти информацию.

Comment: [Input system](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2019/10/14/introducing-the-new-input-system/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
void OnGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.Equals(Event.KeyboardEvent("space")))
    {
        Debug.Log("Кто-то нажал на пробел.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде есть и вариант через интерфейс но с ним некие проблемы. Пытаюсь исправить.

Comment: но ведь я спросил не используя `Update`. И как я знаю, `OnGUI` работает медленнее

Comment: Есть ещё и интерфейс `IKeyboardEvent` Но с ним не всё гладко

Comment: Метод `OnGUI` - это система IMGUI, т.е. проверка `if(keyPressed) DoStuff();`. Это ничем не отличается от проверки в `Update`, разве что работает слегка быстрее.

Comment: Ладно, думаю что использовать `OnGUI` самый оптимальный вариант, ибо создавать отдельные события с методами не очень в плане оптимизации

Comment: @Methorn с чего бы? Каждый кадр будет проверяться условие в `if`'е, когда события будут вызваны по факту возникновения ввода.